# remove duplicate rows based on conditions from multiple columns in r

Tags: r, select, duplicates, conditional-statements

I have a data set I would like to remove the rows of data that have duplicate information in 4 different columns.

```
foo<- data.frame(g1 = c("1","0","0","1","1"), v1 = c("7","5","4","4","3"), v2 = c("a","b","x","x","e"), y1 = c("y","c","f","f","w"), y2= c("y","y","y","f","c"), y3 = c("y","c","c","f","w"), y4= c("y","y","f","f","c"), y5=c("y","w","f","f","w"), y6=c("y","c","f","f","w"))
```

foo then looks like:

```
  g1 v1 v2 y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6
1  1  7  a  y  y  y  y  y  y
2  0  5  b  c  y  c  y  w  c
3  0  4  x  f  y  c  f  f  f
4  1  4  x  f  f  f  f  f  f
5  1  3  e  w  c  w  c  w  w
```

Now, I want to remove any row that has duplicated data based on the Y1-6columns.  So, only row 4 and 1 would be removed if done properly, based on all Y variables being the exact same.  Its a multiple column condition.

I believe I am close, but its just not working correctly.

I have tried: `new = foo[!(duplicated(foo[,1:6]))]`
thinking to use the duplicated command that it would search and only find those that matched exactly?

I thought about using a conditional statement with &, but can't figure out how to do that either.
`new = foo[foo$y1==foo$y2|foo$y3|foo$y4|foo$y5|foo$y6]`

I thought about which but Im now overwhelmed and lost.  I would expect foo to look like:

```
   g1 v1 v2 y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6
2  0  5  b  c  y  c  y  w  c
3  0  4  x  f  y  c  f  f  f
5  1  3  e  w  c  w  c  w  w
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
> foo[apply(foo[ , paste("y", 1:6, sep = "")], 1,
            FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)) > 1 ), ]
  g1 v1 v2 y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6
2  0  5  b  c  y  c  y  w  c
3  0  4  x  f  y  c  f  f  f
5  1  3  e  w  c  w  c  w  w
```

Comment: I apologize I over simplified my example, because I have more columns of information...so based on variable 1-6 ONLY out of say 9 total columns of information.  I will edit the above example

Comment: I updated my answer. Now, the selection of rows is based on columns y1 - y6.

Answer (score 2):

```
foo[apply(foo, 1, function(x) any(x != x[1])),]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> foo[ !rowSums( apply( foo[2:6], 2, "!=", foo[1] ) )==0, ]
  y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6
2  c  y  c  y  w  c
3  f  y  c  f  f  f
5  w  c  w  c  w  w

> foo[ ! colSums( apply( foo, 1, duplicated, foo[1] ) ) == 5, ]
  y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6
2  c  y  c  y  w  c
3  f  y  c  f  f  f
5  w  c  w  c  w  w
```